# Losing the blue highlight on Drag Event in Shopify Draggable

Tags: javascript, draggable

Implementing Shopify's Draggable library with VueJS. From drag:start to drag:stop I'm getting a blue-highlight on the draggable container.

I've tried everything to remove it through CSS, but can't seem to find the right combination to get rid of this ugly effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a css class to the container and remove the `outline` :

```
.draggableContainer {
    outline: none;
}
```

I had to do it with the draggable elements too, not only with the container.